# htaccess wrong redirection with vue router

Tags: php, vue.js, .htaccess, vue-router

I have added a new vue app with vue routere in an old php application.

If I am on the route `www.example.com/foo` and I refresh the page, the php server does not know this URL. So it returns a 404 error. That's ok.

So I have added a `.htaccess` redirection to redirect every request to `index.php`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
```

If my vue-router route is `www.mywebsite.com/foo` and I refresh the page, the `index.php` is always opened, and then vue-router takes over.

If I make an ajax call with `/php/action/ajaxFile.php` URL it works fine.

The problem is when I am in a route like `www.example.com/foo/bar` instead of `www.example.com/foo`, every request is redirected to `/foo/php/action/ajaxFile.php` instead of `/php/action/ajaxFile.php` and that's not ok, because it doesn't find the file...

How can I make it works with multi level URL please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is when I am in a route like `www.example.com/foo/bar` instead of `www.example.com/foo`, every request is redirected to `/foo/php/action/ajaxFile.php` instead of `/php/action/ajaxFile.php`

That sounds like you are (incorrectly) using *relative* URL-paths in your client-side JavaScript (Vue application). If you are at `/foo/bar` and make a request for `php/action/ajaxFile.php` (no slash prefix) then the *browser* will naturally resolve this to `/foo/php/action/ajaxFile.php`.

You need to use root-relative URL-paths (starting with a slash). This has nothing to do with the `.htaccess` file you've posted, which works the same regardless of URL-path depth.

Comment: You were right, thanks, I have replaced all relative paths with absolute path everywhere